# How to attach a security group to aws instance in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying explore terraform to create automate infra in AWS. I am not clear on how to attach a security group to aws instance in terraform.

For example, Is there any property to specify the security groups like here below

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-a1b2c3d4"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the argument `vpc_security_group_ids`. This argument accepts a list of N security group IDs

Answer (score 4):

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-a1b2c3d4"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sec_group" {
  name   = "sec_group"
  vpc_id = "vpc-3324nnrvdl"
}

resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "sg_attachment" {
  security_group_id    = "${data.aws_security_group.sec_group.id}"
  network_interface_id = "${aws_instance.web.primary_network_interface_id}"
}
```

This way you will be able to attach a SG to EC2 instance and both will be in decouple state.

Answer (score 3):

Leveraging from Ay0's answer: you can include `vpc_security_group_ids` rule like:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "basic_security" {
    ingress {...}
    egress {...}
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami                    = "ami-a1b2c3d4"
    instance_type          = "t2.nano"
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.basic_security.id]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can include ***aws_security_group*** like:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
  name        = "sg"
  description = "Web Security Group for HTTP"
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```